# MSSQL Stored Proceedure - Selecting a column by comparing values in different tables

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

WARNING: This is really convoluted and awful, I already know. However, I didn't build the database, I just have to work with it and I cannot change the database schema.

Here are the tables that I'm working with:

**Shot**

ShotID (Identity), FilmID(FK), ShotNumber, .... ,.

**Tag**

TagID (Identity), Name

**TaggedShot**

TaggedShotID (Identity), ShotID (FK), TagID(FK), TagComment

**TaggedCategory**

TagID (FK), CategoryID (FK)

And my stored procedure:

```
    [dbo].[SelectAllTagNames]
        @filmID int,
        @tagCategory int
    AS
        DECLARE @i int
        DECLARE @numRows int
        DECLARE @ShotID int
        DECLARE @TagID int
        DECLARE @TagName nvarchar(50)
        DECLARE @shot_table TABLE(
        idx smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1),
        ShotID int )
        DECLARE @tagID_table TABLE(
        idTag smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1),
        TagID int)
        DECLARE @tagname_table TABLE(
        idTagName smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1),
        TagName nvarchar(50))

//get all shots in the film
        INSERT @shot_table
        SELECT Shot.ShotID
        FROM Shot
        WHERE Shot.FilmID = @filmID

    //enumerate through shot table and build a tagID table of all TagIDs associated with any shot found in the shot_table
        SET @i = 1
        SET @numRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @shot_table)
        IF @numRows > 0
        BEGIN
            WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @shot_table))
            BEGIN

            SET @ShotID = (SELECT ShotID FROM @shot_table WHERE idx = @i)
            SET @TagID = (SELECT TaggedShot.TagID FROM TaggedShot WHERE TaggedShot.ShotID = @ShotID)

            INSERT INTO @tagID_table(TagID)
            VALUES(@TagID)

            SET @i = @i + 1

            END
        END
    //compare each TagID found in tagID_table with the TagID in the TaggedCategory table
// insert Tag.Name into new table if the Tag.TagID matches the TagID in the tagID_table and also matches the given tagCategory
        SET @i = 1
        SET @numRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tagID_table)
        IF @numRows > 0
            WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(idTag) FROM @tagID_table))
                BEGIN
                SET @TagID = (SELECT TagID FROM @tagID_table WHERE idTag = @i)
                IF EXISTS(SELECT TaggedCategory.TagId FROM TaggedCategory WHERE TaggedCategory.CategoryID = @tagCategory)
                    BEGIN

                    SET @TagName = (SELECT Tag.Name FROM Tag WHERE Tag.TagId = @TagID)

                    INSERT INTO @tagname_table(TagName)
                    VALUES(@TagName)

                    END
                END
    //return all the found tag names
    SELECT TagName
    FROM @tagname_table
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
Given FilmID and Tag Category ID (which is just an integer of 1, 2, or 3-- I determined this in the codebehind), I need to find all Tag.Names given those two criteria. A film is comprised of Shots.

Comment: Please edit your question title so that it contains information about the problem itself. "Complicated procedure that I can't wrap my head around" will mean absolutely nothing to future readers here who are searching for solutions. We know it's for a MSSQL stored procedure; you have that information in the tags. Your title should explain something about the problem you're trying to solve or the question you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, sorry, updated title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not tested, but couldn't you handle what you are trying to achieve with simple joins of the tables you provided.  Something like the following:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT t.NAME
 FROM Shot s
 INNER JOIN TaggedShot ts ON s.ShotId = ts.ShotId
 INNER JOIN Tag t ON ts.TagId = t.TagId
 INNER JOIN TaggedCategory tc ON t.TagId = tc.TagId
 WHERE s.FilmId = @filmId
     AND tc.Categoryid = @tagCategory
```

UPDATE based on comment below:

```
 SELECT t.TagId
        ,t.Name
 FROM Tag t
 WHERE t.TagId IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT t.TagId
      FROM Shot s
      INNER JOIN TaggedShot ts ON s.ShotId = ts.ShotId
      INNER JOIN Tag t ON ts.TagId = t.TagId
      INNER JOIN TaggedCategory tc ON t.TagId = tc.TagId
      WHERE s.FilmId = @filmId
          AND tc.Categoryid = @tagCategory)
```

Comment: This works. I'm new to databases and haven't worked with joins. Thank you so much.

Comment: @myeyeros I have another question, what if I also want to return the t.TagId along with t.NAME? However, I cannot say SELECT DISTINCT t.NAME, t.TagId because all TagId's are unique and that would return all rows (and subsequently, duplicate t.NAMEs). I'm looking into the GROUP BY function but it's returning a errors.

Comment: Basically, I want to also retrieve the TagID's that belong to the distinct t.Names.

Comment: You could modify the query that I provided and use it as subquery that returns the distinct tagId values.  Then simply wrap it in another query that hits the Tag table and chooses those tags where the id is in the subquery results.  See updated answer.

Comment: Strange, the logic makes sense to me but it didn't return the correct dataset (it still returned duplicate t.Names). I also tried changing "WHERE t.TagId IN (SELECT DISTINCT t.TagId" to "WHERE t.Name IN (SELECT DISTINCT t.Name" and it returned even MORE duplicate t.Names.